# Debugging TypeScript code with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Is there a way to debug TypeScript source in Visual Studio (instead of debugging the generated javascript)?

From the TypeScript language specifications:

> TypeScript optionally provides source maps, enabling source-level debugging.

I was therefore expecting to be able to place breakpoints in ts code and be able to debug it, but it doesn't work. I didn't find any other mentions of debugging in the specs. Is there anything I should do to make this work? Perhaps the word "optionally" hints that I need to do something for it to work... Any suggestions?

Comment: You can also check out the [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typescript/9131/)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Current Answer for VS2017 and later**

Debugging Typescript directly in Visual Studio has been possible since VS2017. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/debug-nodejs?view=vs-2019):

> You can debug JavaScript and TypeScript code using Visual Studio. You can set and hit breakpoints, attach the debugger, inspect variables, view the call stack, and use other debugging features.

There are also additional resources on [Debugging Typescript / Asp.NET Core in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-aspnet-with-typescript?view=vs-2019).

It is also possible to debug typescript in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging):

> Visual Studio Code supports TypeScript debugging through its built-in Node.js debugger and also through extensions like Debugger for Chrome to support client-side TypeScript debugging.

**Original Answer for prior versions of VS:**

You may not be able to debug in VS, but you can in some browsers. Aaron Powell has blogged about getting breakpoints working in Chrome Canary just today: https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2012-10-03-typescript-source-maps/.

To summarise (very briefly) what Aaron says, you use the `-sourcemap` switch on the compiler to generate a `*.js.map` file in the same directory as your source. In browsers which support [source maps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) (Chrome Canary, and presumably recent Firefox builds, since they are a Mozilla idea), you can then debug your `.ts` source just as you would normal `.js` files.

The blog finishes with "Hopefully either the Visual Studio or IE (or both) team also pick up Source Maps and add support for them too." - which suggests it hasn't happened yet.

**Update:**

With the release of TypeScript 0.8.1, Source Map debugging is now also available in Visual Studio:

https://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2012/11/15/announcing-typescript-0-8-1.aspx

From the announcement:

> **Debugging**
>   TypeScript now supports source level debugging!  The source map format
>   has been gaining popularity as a way of debugging languages which
>   translate to JavaScript and is supported by a variety of browsers and
>   tools.  With version 0.8.1, the TypeScript compiler officially
>   supports source maps.  Additionally, the new version of TypeScript for
>   Visual Studio 2012 supports debugging using the source map format.
>        From the command-line, we now fully support the use of the --sourcemap flag, which outputs a source map file corresponding to the JavaScript output.  This file will allow directly debugging the
>   original TypeScript source in source map-enabled browsers and Visual
>   Studio.
>        To enable debugging in Visual Studio select ‘Debug’ from the dropdown after creating an HTML Application with TypeScript project.

**Update**:

WebStorm has also added support for debugging via SourceMaps: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/webstorm-6-0-released-adds-typescript-debugging-with-source-maps-fresh-ui-and-much-more/

> First, WebStorm allows for smarter and more streamlined web
>   development with modern languages such as TypeScript, CoffeeScript and
>   Dart. In addition to providing a first-class code editor for these
>   languages, WebStorm 6 offers:
>
> Automatic compilation/transpilation of these higher-level languages
>   into those recognized by browsers on all supported platforms.
>   Full-featured debugging of TypeScript, Dart or CoffeeScript with
>   source maps.

Comment: Is Chrome Canary really required? I'm on Chrome stable, and I see "enable source maps" is an option in the developer tools settings window.

Comment: I think when Aaron wrote the blog (and when I posted this answer), Canary was necessary. By now, the feature must have percolated through to release.

Comment: Now, it seems to be possible to debug TypeScript directly in the Visual Studio GUI when using Internet Explorer. I wonder if this can be achieved with other browsers, too.

Comment: I can't get VS 2012 to debug TS

Comment: Worked for me by generating source maps with "Web Extensions"

Comment: @Nikos, assuming you have the most recent version of TypeScript, ensure you are using @Script.Render(~/bundles/your_bundle) and you of course, you are bundling your TS using ScriptBundle.  Also, if you are outputting a single .js from the TS compiler ensure you have -sourcemap option enabled.  These worked for me, although by accident.

Comment: I was wondering. Debugging TS works great for me in VS 2017. However, don't we really need to also debug the output js files?  How is this done?

Answer (score 15):

With VS2013 Typescript application, I didn't have to change anything in web.config. I put a breakpoint in the ts file and debugged in IE, and presto, the breakpoint stopped inside TypeScript.

Comment: I agree. I am using VS 2013 Update 2.

Comment: Thank you for pointing on IE. Unfortunately debugging is not working in Chrome.

Comment: My guess is that Microsoft leverages some hooks in ie to make the debug process work which other browsers don't support yet. There is an intermediate code mapping file which is like a contract between the generated javascript in the browser and the source code in the IDE. I am just glad it works at all.

Answer (score 5):

This is now fixed in VS 2017 so you can debug directly in Visual Studio and typescript.

Just set your breakpoint in your *.ts file, and it will be hit.

And it will debug in VS, not IE, as if you were debugging c#.

Answer (score 3):

Debugging typescript with Visual Studio works with the right settings. (In previous versions of VS I face problems sometimes, below is how it works fine with VS 2015 CTP 6)

1. First you **make sure that you create source maps** when compiling typescript to javascript. So you should have an xxx.js.map file near every xxx.js.

   Getting source maps by running the typescript compiler outside of Visual Studio does not cause any difficulty, at the tsc command line add

   ```
   --sourcemap %1.ts
   ```

   your gulp script will usually create sourcemaps by default.
2. **Configure your web application in Visual Studio**.

   Set **Internet Explorer** as the start browser. I got it working only with IE and dont think any other browser will work.

   In the project properties go to the "Web" tab and configure the "Debuggers" section at the bottom: **Disable all debuggers**! This is counter intutitive and you might see this  error message:

   *You have attempted to start the debugger, but based on your current debug settings on the Web properties page there is no process to debug. This occurs when the "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from another process" option is selected, and ASP.NET debugging is disabled. Please check your settings on the Web properties page and try again.*

   As the error message says, the Start Action at the top of the Web properties should be another option, like "**Current page**".

   Set **breakpoints** in your ts code inside Visual Studio now or later.

   Hit **F5**

While you can use the Visual Studio Editor to debug and edit ts files, "Edit and Continue" will not work, there is currently no browser that can reload js and js.map files and continue. (Correct me anyone if I am wrong and I will be happy.)

Comment: any changes to your setup since april?

Comment: did you find the writeup useful?

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript debugging didn't work for me at all with VS2013 Update 3 on any of my machines.  After much frustration, I decided to try updating to VS2013 Update 4 CTP.  Finally breakpoints are being hit in VS!

Comment: thx for update 4 ctp heads up, installing. my machine has Update 3 and typescript debugging works. however, starting ie takes a long time in particular since every time the web application is compiled (although i changed only ts code)

Answer (score -1):

short answer: Restart Visual Studio

background:
I had 2 visual studio 2015 instances with two different projects with TypeScript. The first started instance did not debug correctly, the second one did.
All of the project settings were the same.
I finally restarted the first instance and then it debugged TypeScript (finally).

Comment: may work in some cases, but as a general tip its not useful.