# Typescript debugging with single file

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to compile all my typescript into an single file (app.js etc.) and debug inside the .ts files ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here.

1. Use [Source Maps to debug your TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711826/debugging-typescript-code-with-visual-studio) - only supported in a couple of browsers.
2. Get cosy with the JavaScript - the more you debug in pure JavaScript using browser consoles, the better your understanding will be.
3. Bundle for debug and test / live separately. If you debug over multiple files you can do it in Visual Studio. You can then use the single file on other environments.

Comment: i use sourcemaps. i like to compile all typescript in a single .js file and then debug my typescript files. it doesnt work since the compiler create only the sourcemap for the single .js file.