# TypeScript Build setting "Compile on Save" does not work in VS 2015, .js file is generated only during build

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

**EDIT**

Why is this issue **extremely painful**? So far while I debugged/tested my Web App I've just edited the .ts in VS IDE, saved, then reloaded the page and tested the changes. Now I have to build. However build is not enabled when debug session is running in the VS IDE. So now I have to do a complete roundtrip: edit .ts -> save ->  stop debugging -> build -> launch debug. Again, this is extremely painful.
**END EDIT**

I've unchecked / saved / checked the setting in TypeScript Build tab in my project setting.

[image]

The appropriate `<PropertyGroup>` was generated and saved to my .csproj file.

(note without changing any TypeScript Build setting, this `<PropertyGroup>` is not there (when using an existing project what was previously created with VS 2013), and the *build*  defaults are not the same as the defaults on the *IDE UI* so you are misleaded.)

Anyway after this change / save activity my .csproj file is in sync with the IDE UI here it is:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>True</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
  <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
  <TypeScriptModuleKind>None</TypeScriptModuleKind>
  <TypeScriptOutFile />
  <TypeScriptOutDir />
  <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
  <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  <TypeScriptMapRoot />
  <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
</PropertyGroup>
```

As it shows the Compile on Save is definitely enabled. Still the .js file only generated during build and not when the .ts file was saved.

Btw: Regarding that TypeScript compile is an *msbuild task* in VS 2015 implementation it is interesting how could this Compile on save setting even work...

More diagnostics:
Interestingly in case if I delete the whole propertygroup then it actually compiles on save. (The UI remains the same, and the .map files are not generated on the save, only on build.)

Comment: I create a single output js-file in my typescript project. If I build, it still creates a js-file for each ts-file. If I compile on save, it output to a single js-file, correctly. Strange, buggy, time-consuming, and frustrating experience. Sometimes the ts-files get out of order, if I open _references.ts and saves inside that file, it follows the reference order and the js-output is correct again. I have not been able to find the "correct" way to compile multiple ts-file to a single js-file, yet - if there is one.

Answer (score 4):

did you look for the "Tools" menu < options... < Typescript < project and check the "compile on save" checkbox ?

Comment: I have no such option... It is just me?

Comment: nope, I don't have that option/category.. (@2015 Update 1)

Comment: The settings for Typescript exist under `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Typescript -> Project`

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.... Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Typescript -> Project  is the place to enable Auto compile on save

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been looking for the answer for awhile, this solved it for me! :)

Comment: This is still not working. Now I am battling with the very same issue with VS 2017. Now I have that auto compile option, but is say "Automatically compile.... which are *not* part of project". And btw does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working finally by adding `"compileOnSave": true` to my `tsconfig.json`.

So you tsconfig should look like :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
         ....
    },
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me when i moved `compileOnSave` to **before** `compilerOptions` in the `tsconfig` file.

Comment: Indeed, this was my problem. I had `compileOnSave ` below the options and wondered why it did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, so I:

1. followed citykid's [advise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29465988/164680),
2. **created .js.map** file by myself,
3. tried your guide - it started to work, however I

   - compared PropertyGroup section which was slightly different, thus I tested your's config and
4. re-enabled debuggers from citykid's advise

... And it still works like charm.

---

It could be irrelevant but I have:

- Visual Studio Pro 14.0.23107.0
- Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 14.0.60814.0
- TypeScript for MS VS 1.6.3.0 (!)
- Web Essentials 0.5.197 installed
- Web Compiler 1.8.270 installed
- Bundler & Minifier **not** installed
- ReSharper 9.2 (?)

---

To test it, I recommend to:

1. open .js.map,
2. modify .ts by adding function - .js.map reloads,
3. debug in IE,
4. modify .ts by adding function - .js.map reloads,
5. reload page and it should reflect changes in both debugger and browser.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2019:

Step 1 **Tools** > **Options** :

[image]

Step 2 In your tsconfig.json:

```html
{
  "compileOnSave": true,    <---- insert before compilerOptions
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```