# Typescript in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, typescript

I am working on an Angular 4.X project and using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 as IDE. So far I am able to debug my Typescript code in the browser (mostly Google Chrome) but I want to know if there is a way out using which I can put breakpoints and debug the Typescript right from the Visual Studio itself.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just VS2017 supports this feature, if you have to use VS2015, you would think about using other workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711826/debugging-typescript-code-with-visual-studio

Comment: Could you get useful information? If you have any debugging issues, please feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is supported only in Visual Studio 2017 you can see how to enable it[here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/)