# Visual Studio shows wrong value for `this` in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript, typescript1.4

Consider following code:

```
class Person{
    firstname = ko.observable<string>();
    lastname: ko.observable<string>();
    fullname = ko.computed(()=>{

        // Breakpoint here
        return this.firstname() + ' ' + this.lastname();

    });
```

when I'm debugging with Visual Studio 2013, if I put a breakpoint and see the value of `this` using watch or immediate window, it shows that the value is `window` not the person instance. Consequently, it shows `undefined` for `this.firstname`.

Checking the converted JavaScript code I find out that I should check the value of `_this` instead of `this`.

Although code runs without an error, but it waste lots of my time to understand that the true value of `this` variable is available through `_this`.

**Question** Am I somewhere wrong in using the class properties which causes this misleading value in `this` value? or it's just a bug? or maybe it's by design for some reason?

Comment: @Bergi this question is not the duplicate question. This question is been asked 4 years ago and your referred question is being asked 3 years ago. So if there is a duplicate one, that question should be considered as a duplicate!

Comment: Yes, they're duplicates of each other. You did nothing wrong, your question being closed doesn't mean any harm to you. I chose the other question as the canonical one because it doesn't have knockout-specific code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Due to how the "this" keyword works in javascript Typescript creates the "_this" alias for you. This is by design, and is great when you know how it works.

Your example:

```
class Person {
    firstname = ko.observable<string>();
    lastname: ko.observable<string>();
    fullname = ko.computed(
        () => {
            // Breakpoint here
            return this.firstname() + ' ' + this.lastname();
    });
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person() {
        var _this = this;
        this.firstname = ko.observable();
        this.lastname = ();
        this.fullname = ko.computed(function () {
            // Breakpoint here
            return _this.firstname() + ' ' + _this.lastname();
        });
    }
    return Person;
})();
```

This shows (as you mentioned) that "this" in your fullname computed  function has been compiled to "_this". Your issue with the debugging is that Visual Studio is debugging the compiled javascript. And in javascript "this" inside the function means something else, read more about "this" in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Typescript creates a _this reference when you use a lambda function, i.e:

```
class foo {

    something: string = "some string";

    foo1 = () => { this.something }
    foo2() { this.something }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
var foo = (function () {
    function foo() {
        var _this = this;
        this.something = "some string";
        this.foo1 = function () { _this.something; };
    }
    foo.prototype.foo2 = function () { this.something; };
    return foo;
})();
```

If used correctly lambda functions in typescript solves the "this" hell from javascript. In most cases you do not need to think about when to use lambdas or functions, but in some cases you do. More information about lambda functions can be found [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/).

The short answer for working with this is to inspect _this when working with lambdas until it is fixed. 
There is an open issue for it: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1655.

Comment: The problem is that Visual Studio should show the correct value for `this`. The `this` in the equivalent JavaScript has different meaning than the `this` in TypeScript. In JavaScript there are `this` and `_this` with different values. But in the original TypeScript there is only one `this` which is equivalent with `_this` value in JavaScript code.

Comment: Indeed, it is a tooling problem more than anything else. It seems likely to be something we will have to live with for a while to since the issue has been known and not fixed for a while. https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1655

Comment: because of the _this I use the Visual Studio "Watch" Window and add "_this" to the window and so I can see what values are set

Comment: @Nypan screaaaaam... as  you requested!

Comment: Looks like [the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2617) is still open…

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just stumbled on one of the hassle of JavaScript. "this is driving me crazy, but I have no idea what this is referring to". So this is not a bug, this is by design. Long story short, JavaScript rescopes `this` according to the context. This is particularly problematic when using libraries such as d3 (for events callbacks) or angular, or knockout in your case. This problem becomes inherintly more obvious when using TypeScript because you have to use `this` everywhere.
You can find more documentation about the use of `this` on [the mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

To circumvent your problem, the easiest solution is to keep a reference to the original `this` before entering your callback, and use the local variable inside, i.e.:

```
class Person{
  firstname = ko.observable<string>();
  lastname: ko.observable<string>();
  var self = this;
  fullname = ko.computed(()=>{

    // Breakpoint here
    return self.firstname() + ' ' + self.lastname();

  });
```

This is an habit I suggest you adopt to avoid future problems, and is kind of a good practice in JavaScript.

Comment: I do not consider it good practise to define your own self reference in TypeScript since typescript does this for you, you just need to know when and how to use lambdas and the problem with "this" goes away. Se my answer below.

Comment: I have not any problem with the REAL value of `this` in TypeScript, because it's true. The only problem is that the debugger shows it incorrectly.

Comment: Is this a recent improvement? I went the `self`way because I had some problems when using `this`. That's good to know, thanks for the information.