# Multiple ways to declare a function on a TypeScript interface: how are they different?

Tags: typescript

I've seen properties that are functions declared in multiple ways, as illustrated by `func1` and `func2` on this TypeScript interface:

```
interface Thing {
    func: (arg:string) => number;
    func2(arg:string): number;
}
```

Is there a difference between the two? Is there a case in which you would use one over the other?

[This playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20Thing%20%7B%0D%0A%09func%3A%20(arg%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20number%3B%0D%0A%09func2(arg%3Astring)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20thing%3A%20Thing%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09func%3A%20(foo%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%202%2C%0D%0A%09func2%3A%20(foo%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20first%3A%20number%20%3D%20thing.func(%22hello%22)%3B%0D%0Avar%20second%3A%20number%20%3D%20thing.func2(%22hello%22)%3B) seems to imply that the two can be used interchangeably. Are there any limits to this?

Comment: My answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056593/visual-studio-shows-wrong-value-for-this-in-typescript/30070859#30070859 answers this quite well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a difference between the two

Yes.

`func: (arg:string) => number;`

This version means its a property. This will limit you when you try to declare `overloads`.

`func2(arg:string): number;`

This is preferred for functions as this means that you can easily declare overloads after the fact (using the open ended nature of interfaces)

> seems to imply that the two can be used interchangeably

That is because they are *type compatible*. Does not mean that *they are the same thing*. See property vs. method below:

[image]

[image]

## Example

This should clarify :

```
interface Thing {
    func: (arg: string) => number;
    func2(arg:string): number;
}

interface Thing {
    // Overload not permitted
    func: (arg: number) => string; // ERROR!
    // Overload okay 
    func2(arg: number): string;
}
```