# phaser js undefined variable within loading function

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I'm just starting out using phaser JS for game dev but have come across a an odd issue which I need some help on.

Let me show my code and explain where things are going wrong:

```js
class SimpleGame {
    game: Phaser.Game;
    csvTM: string;
    
    constructor (csvTM: string) {

        this.csvTM = csvTM;

        this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create });
    }

    test() {
        console.log("map test: " + this.csvTM);
    }

    preload() {
        console.log("map preload: " + this.csvTM);
        this.game.load.image('logo', 'empty_room.png');
        this.game.load.tilemap("ItsTheMap", this.csvTM, null, Phaser.Tilemap.CSV);
        this.game.load.image("Tiles", "concrete.png");
    }

    create() {
        console.log("map create: " + this.csvTM);
        var map = this.game.add.tilemap('ItsTheMap', 32, 32);
        map.addTilesetImage("Tiles");
        var layer = map.createLayer(0);
        layer.resizeWorld();

    }

}
```

Now what i'm trying to do here is simply pass a csv file path to the constructor of the SimpleGame object.  When just using an absolute path, everything works just fine and i'l able to see the grid, etc. The issue comes in when I try to use the variable. Notice I have three log statements all displaying the contents of csvTM variable.  Now what I do is first:

```js
var game = new SimpleGame(msg["Commands"][0][1]);
            game.test();
```

which loads the new phaser object and passes the file path into the constructor.  Now im 100% sure the local variable csvTM is set becuase when I do teh game.test() above I see the file path. However in preload and create the csvTM is always undefined.. thus breaking my code.  I do notice that the game object which is also made in the constructor seems to work and is always defined.

Does anyone know why my local variable string is undefined in only preload and create while the game local variable seems to be defined?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard for me to be sure about this since I do not have access to all of your code. But I think it might be a case of the classic javascript "this" problem.

Try defining the methods as:

```
preload = () =>  { ... }
create = () =>  { ... }
```

This will make sure that "this" inside the functions is actually the correct "version" of "this".

There are many questions (and answers) about how "this" works in typescript/javascript on stackoverflow but my answer to a previous similar question might explain why you are getting this behaviour: [Visual Studio shows wrong value for `this` in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056593/visual-studio-shows-wrong-value-for-this-in-typescript/30070859#30070859)

EDIT:

As Marwane K.A. pointed out in his comment to my answer the issue can be solved by replacing

```
{ preload: this.preload, create: this.create }
```

in the initiation with "this".

Comment: Agreed with the diagnosis, except I think it might simply be resolved by replacing `{ preload: this.preload, create: this.create }` by just `this` in the game init.

Comment: I did not notice that! Thanks, updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I'm not sure understand? The preload and create are basically hash keys mapping to a function address/value.  If i were to replace the entire mapping with just "this" it would just be a reference to the class with the preload and create functions and not a hash anymore?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ES6 classes but AFAIK there's no difference between passing \{ preload: this.preload, create: this.create }` and `this`, except for the very issue we're discussing. Both are basically just javascript objects with properties preload & create mapped to functions.

(EDIT: Well, there are other differences actually, but all in all Phaser shouldn't notice a thing)

Comment: The difference (at least the one we care about here) is what `this` is. In the case where you pass a new object (with the `{ ... }`) `this` inside the functions will be that new object, and not the `this` from the `SimpleGame` instance.