# Angular 2.0 with JavaScript or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Which is the recommended way to develop angular 2.0 application. is it with javascript or typescript. i found difficult to start the angular 2.0 with typescript which is entirely different from the javascript.

Comment: I don't think there can be an objective answer to this question (I just flagged it as opinion-based). Maybe you just have to try and follow some tutorials in both options, and choose what suits you best

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript)

Comment: got my vote up because I'm also confused in choosing between `TypeScript` and `JavaScript`. after doing a little bit search on google, I have found a great [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-TypeScript) to understand.

Comment: @JitendraTiwari then what is your conclusion ??  could you share the url for that video

Comment: I decide to use `TypeScript` and this is really easy to understand. I have never use `TypeScript` before. Infact some tutorials are not available in `Javascript` or `DART` for now.

Comment: I have already share url with you. but now https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-TypeScript

Answer (score 3):

In fact, TypeScript is a superset of ES6. In short, you will have the following in addition:

- Type checking (class properties, method parameters)
- Decorators
- Interfaces

Perhaps the gap between ES5 and ES6 / TypeScript is important but there are really advantages to use it:

- The compilation phase allows you to detect potential problems in your case
- TypeScript provides contracts (.d.ts files) of the elements / third-party libraries you use
- Support of IDE for completion

That said, you are free to use either ES5, ES6 or TypeScript. It's up to you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the decision must depend on the knowledge and experience of your team so that you can make a close time estimation of your project and avoid unwanted issue that might occur in lack of knowledge and experience. Hope my suggestion will help you to decide. Thanks.