# Use NPM to create a production build of an Angular2 project

Tags: angular, npm

I created a project using the Angular2 quickstart https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

I changed it completely to do my things, some usage of webcams, indexedDB and things like that :-).

The thing right now is that I've been using npm as the site recommends and it feels wrong now just changing to Gulp to create a build, instead of creating a build script on npm.

The next issue is that I've never done such a thing and I'm completely lost... do you know of any build script I could use/adapt? Or should I switch to Gulp?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by creating a production build? Are you talking about stopping the `"Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode."`

Comment: Thank you for commenting Gabriele, I don't quite follow. I guess running in production mode would change some ways in which angular 2 behaves, things it tracks down or performance improvements, whatever.

I don't think it will provide me with an index.html with a vendor.js and an app.js minified and all that, you know what I mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see, now I think I understand where the misunderstanding is. The link you provided is for Angular2 using Javascript. The best way to create a production Angular2 build is to use Typescript (and I believe it's the only officially supported way at this point as well). [Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/index.html) is a link to the tutorial using Typescript. If you don't know what that is, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript) a SO question on it.

Once you learn how to use Angular2 with Typescript, I recommend reading [this](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-run-angular-2-in-production-today/) article on Angular2 in production.

Also, they are currently working on a command-line interface that will automatically build your app for production. They've released it but it's buggy at this point.

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you! I'm already using typescript, sorry for the wrong link.
I think creating a npm script that uses the typescript to get all required js (vendor and custom) together would be awesome, but couldn't find anything about it, I guess is not trivial :-). I let this open some more days in case we get a "better" answer, if not I'll mark yours and try to build something myself, if I succed I'll post here again.

Comment: @RollWhisTler I'd just like to add that if you use the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), you can run `ng build -prod` and it will turn your project into just html and css and 1 js file that holds all the code for the project. It increases performance significantly.

Comment: Yes, sadly angular-cli is not updated to latest @angular dependencies notation, or it wasn't last time I checked. I want to take a look at webpack.

Comment: The dependencies have been updated to RC3 (I updated the cli yesterday). If you want to use webpack, here's the [documentation for using webpack from the angular website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) (in case you haven't seen it yet)

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest my project [Zwitterion](https://github.com/lastmjs/zwitterion). Zwitterion is a server that allows you to include TypeScript files directly in the browser, and will automatically transpile all imported modules in your application. To do a production build, you run Zwitterion with the `--build-static` command. It's extremely simple, and if you'd like to learn more check out [the article](https://hackernoon.com/zwitterion-transpilation-made-simple-a9baa407b006) or the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/lastmjs/zwitterion).