# vscode Intellisense NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

In vscode, developers have the ability to hover over methods and properties of variables and objects in our code, and it will show you information regarding them. Unfortunately, that is lost once we pass the code to a module inside of another file (since javascript is statically typed). Is there any way possible for me to explicitly type a parameter passed to a module? Or maybe a source-map of some sort? An example of where I have an issue:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var routes = './routes/route.js'
```

**route.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    // Hovering over app doesn't show the intellisense like it does in app.js
}
```

#### Update

I have continued searching for the answer but have not found one. This is the closest to getting it to work I have got, but for some reason, the editor doesn't want to apply the type. See below:

**route.js**

```
import Express from 'Express'

/**
* @param {Express} app
*/        
module.exports = function(app) {
    // Hovering over app doesn't show the intellisense like it does in app.js
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/node-debugging

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense No, because that is for client side debugging. I am strictly referring to what's happening server side. Also, I am not referring to actual debugging - I am referring to the Intellisense(while developing).

Comment: Have the same issue! This should be supported in the most recent version, however there's a bug (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11825) it's targeted for TypeScript 2.7 ...
Mean while put `import {Express} from 'express'` at the top of the file will make intelissense work, but you'll have to comment it out when not using TypeScript so your code works.

Answer (score 6):

> ...since javascript is statically typed.

JavaScript not statically typed. It is dynamically typed.

> Is there any way possible for me to explicitly type a parameter passed to a module?

Yes. Use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). It provides [optional static typing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694578/1108891).

#### Explanation

In the following screenshot, the Intellisense does work. It is showing that `app` is of type `any`. That is the best we can do with JavaScript, because JavaScript is dynamically typed. At compile time, `app` can indeed be `any` type. Being dynamically typed means that the type is checked only at runtime.

[image]

Comment: Good catch man, I put the inverse of what I meant.  I like this explanation most so far.. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that VS Code has no way to determine that `app` is actually of the type `Express`. This is why your second version of `route.js` seems to make sense.

The problem with that, is that object types are not supported in JSDoc as interpreted by VS Code.

VS Code internally uses the JavaScript Language Service, as [shown here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense). The thing is, the JavaScript Language Service itself is actually TypeScript (see the links to it on the same page).

This answers your question in the following ways:

First, The JSDoc annotations supported by VS Code are the same as those [supported by TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript). And from the [TypeScript documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript), this is not supported:

```
/**
 * @param {object} param1 - Listing properties on an object type does not work
 * @param {string} param1.name
 */
function fn7(param1) {}
```

And that's why your second attempt didn't work.

But this is supported:

```
/** @type {{a: string, b: number}} */
var var12;
```

So if you're very adventurous indeed, you could add the most-needed properties that way. I don't think that's even worth the effort.

The final alternative would be to actually use TypeScript. It doesn't need to make a huge difference to your code and will give you the type information you need.

So I created a `route.ts` that looks like this:

```
import 'node';
import { Express } from 'Express';

module.exports = function(app: Express) {
    // Your code with IntelliSense goes here
}
```

This preserves the type information and IntelliSense and works like a charm. The trade-off is that you require one more build step (which you can handle transparently in your task runner or with `tsc --watch`).

Then again, you get the IntelliSense you want without being bound to ES6 (default TypeScript config uses ES5) and without being forced to use any more TypeScript than you want. All the rest of your code can be plain JavaScript if you feel like it.

To recap, your three alternatives are:

1. No IntelliSense.
2. Type annotations that explicitly list needed properties or functions.
3. Use TypeScript type annotations.

**Edit**: I should add that I also installed the TypeScript type imports for both Node and Express. I'm not sure if they are explicitly needed, but you should probably install them if you want to go this route.

Use this:

```
npm install @types/node
npm install @types/express
```

Comment: I honestly don't know why I didn't start using typescript sooner. I don't understand why vanilla javascript doesn't go this route...

Comment: Vanilla JavaScript cannot go this route, because it is dynamically typed.

Comment: Actually, there is a lot in TypeScript that I like. The type annotation is merely its gateway drug.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really useful feature in VS Code that enables Synthetic Default Imports. It will automatically import typing information from the JSDoc or from type definition files.

I've linked a [blog post](https://blog.tallan.com/2017/03/02/synthetic-type-inference-in-javascript/) that shows you both how to get setup, and a practical example of the functionality it

Answer (score -3):

I think a better solution would be this:

```
function myFunc() {
    //damn code
}

export default myFunc
```

As you can see, the function is not wrapped, but requires es6 ;)

Comment: What does this have to do with my question?

Comment: Did u try that? You said that you will lose informations about methods if you're wrapping in module.exports = {}..

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It doesn't change the intellisense. I still need to pass the app parameter to the exported module as well.