# Angular2 with Typescript

Tags: angular

Why yo use transpiler for converting ts file to js for that we can directly use js itself

Help me out

Comment: Then why are you using Angular not vanilla JS?

Comment: Is Angular2 only support typescipt?

Comment: Check this question [What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript) . and this  [Angular: Why TypeScript?](https://vsavkin.com/writing-angular-2-in-typescript-1fa77c78d8e8). You'll get your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

When you are developing a web app sometimes it becomes very important to decide the type of the variables to avoid errors. JavaScript does dynamic typing of the variables. In typescript you have the choice to give types of the variables statically or dynamically.
Typescript has much more advanced and user-friendly Object Oriented Programming than JavaScript.
It saves huge lines of codes and makes the code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks Md Shahnawaz

Comment: Then what is the use of converting typesript to javascript using transpiler

Comment: Browser can understand JavaScript and not Typescript.