# refresh typescript data from jfxPanel java

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, jfxpanel

I have a JFX panel that run typeScript.
I want to execute typeScript function that trigger by java function.

there is a: `engine.executeScript("scriptName");`
but its working just on **javaScript** function and doesnt know the **TypeScript** function.

I try this option:
I create JS page that try to call to TS function
like this code:

in jfxPanelManager.java

```
engine.executeScript("realoadMe()");
```

in bridge.js

```
var app=requierd('./home/app.ts');

function reloadMe(){
    app.reloadData();
}
```

java throw exeption that the app in undefined.

How can I refresh the data?

Comment: for your approach to succeed without considerable effort you need to compile to JavaScript (js), before you try to run it in a web-view, if you are not aware of differences between js and typescript see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript/35048303#35048303

Comment: I try and put an convert ts code but the error (in java) **'undefine' is not an object (Componenet1.component)** \ my code in JS is: `Component1=requierd('./Component'); Component1.component.prototype.func();`

Comment: you have 'var app=requierd('./home/app.ts');'  should be 'var app=require('./home/app.ts');' but that is a different issue to running typescript instead of  javascript