# import and export keywords belongs to JavaScript or TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Reading [angular](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-vs-jsmodule) docs and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) docs , states that `import` and `export` keywords belongs to JavaScript.

But feel little confused when same keywords is used as [Reserved Keywords](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#2.2.1) in TypeScript.

So `import` and `export` belongs to which programming language JavaScript or TypeScript ?

Comment: Do you understand that TypeScript is just a superset which in the end gets compiled down to Javascript?

Comment: They belong to JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript is part of TypeScript. If these keywords belong to JS, they are belong to TS too.

Comment: Take any valid JS file, rename it to `.ts`, it's a valid TS file. That's what a superset is.

Comment: @dfsq , yes I do understand that. But Why do both use same keyword. And if its a `JavaScript` keyword why we need to compile to `JavaScript` again ?

Comment: TypeScript uses ES6 imports https://blog.jdriven.com/2017/06/typescript-and-es6-import-syntax/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , Thanks , I initially thought that `Typescript` was separate programming language with its own syntax , Now I know that it uses `JavaScript` and `ES6` syntax along with its type system of `TypeScript` is relatively rich, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35048303/2218697).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeScript` is just a superset of `JavaScript`, hence every keyword that belongs to `JavaScript` automatically belongs to `TypeScript` as well.

This is not limited to only `import` and `export`, but also to several others like `delete` and some more.

I am not extraordinarily versed in `TypeScript`, but I can imagine that there are reserved words as well specifically for this programming language.

Comment: And if its a JavaScript keyword why we need to compile to `JavaScript` again ? So why use `Type script` then ? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35048303/2218697) answered my question. Because The type system of `TypeScript` is relatively rich.

Comment: Well, I can see why a lot of people do like `TypeScript`, but as far as I am concerned I don't see the need when you are writing clean code in `JavaScript`. Since it is a superset this opens discussions wether it is useful at all, especially with the current development of `ES6` and `ESNext`, which provide a lot of features that were polyfilled by `TypeScript`.

And one more thing to note: Because `TypeScript` is 'just' a superset it will always stay behind a bit when new features get released within `JavaScript`. This might not seem of importance but is definitely something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript so it has same keywords which Javascript has. 
Main purpose of typescript is to make easy to the Developer to develop the app using the oops concepts any backend developer also can built an app. If any one tries to develop big application using Javascript then It will take too much time to implement and code will become more complex. Though Typescript is based on OOPS concept but after all it transform into Javascript so it also not able to implements all the concepts of oops. Main thing is as I said It's easy to code in TypeScript rather then pure Javascript. Same as Jquery we are using for our comfort.

Comment: One more feature of typescript : `ES6` JavaScript is a superset of `ES5` JavaScript, But it doesnt run in many browsers. 
`ES5` is the kind of JavaScript that runs natively in all modern browsers. 
The transformation of TypeScript code all the way down to `ES5` code can be seen as "shedding" features. Thanks to that, using Typescript, you have all the es6 typings even when targeting es5 check [this](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration) and [this](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html).