# Building VS Code Extensions in Typescript vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Are there any benefits of developing a Visual Studio Code extension in Typescript rather than JavaScript? I've been searching for a comparison of the two (pros, cons, differences, etc) but have not been able to find that.

Comment: I don't think there are any specific benefits, at runtime it's all Javascript, the advatages are those that TS offers generally that stem from type safety: easier to discover an unfamiliar  API, less changes of errors, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would definitley use typescript.  VSCode was made in typescript and it would be a good idea to use the same language they use.  The extension [examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples) they offer are all in typescript.  Other people's extensions like my [own](https://github.com/Almenon/vscode-extension-boilerplate) or [wolf](https://github.com/Duroktar/Wolf) or [react-native](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/) or [power-mode](https://github.com/hoovercj/vscode-power-mode) are also in typescript.  If you used javascript using other people's code would require converting it over which would be quite annoying.

And of course there are all the benefits typescript provides over javascript: fail-fast compilation, better intellisense, less errors, etc...

[What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript)