# Are there any recommendations about the showcases for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am in the middle of TypeScript course, and would like to try some showcases in order to better understand the concepts.

Are there any showcases, like from level 0 to higher standards?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is the biggest advantage of **Type**Script? It's the **type safety** it provides compared to plain ECMA-/JavaScript.

So I'd start with some examples showing how TypeScript keeps you from mixing up types and producing runtime errors.

Then you could go on with the concept of methods, interfaces and generics.

Just try to find out the differences between TS and ECMA / JavaScript.