# JavaScript any way to declare strict type variables

Tags: javascript, java

Hy I am a new to JavaScript. I have done programming with Java. In Java we declares variables with proper type. string, int, char etc. Is there a way to declare variable in JavaScript having proper type instead of let, var etc.

Comment: There are no strict types in native JavaScript but you can take a look on TypeScript.

Comment: Javascript is a dynamically typed language, if you want static typing, take a look at [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [Flow](https://flow.org/)

Comment: See [What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12694530). I'm not voting for a dupe, as it's only one of the possibilities - another alternative is Flow. There are other static typing systems available, as well. I've used Tern.JS in the past and it had nice integrations with some editors. It further took the types from JSDoc, so it worked on plain JS, while TS and Flow need a compilation step.

Answer (score 0):

While using javascript stack *(javascript, typescript)* you are going to use `let/const` but you can either strictly define the type like:

> let a: number = 5;

or leave it to javascript engine

> let b = 5;

Comment: `let a: number = 5;` throws an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` in console.

Comment: you have to run it in a file with extensions [.ts] not [.js]

Comment: ok. my bad. apologies

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a dynamically typed language, the type is assigned by the javascript itself, it has some ways of assigning types to variables, but none natively, they all need some framework.
The most famous way is [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) which is a superset of javascript, other way is [flow.js](https://flow.org/).

If you want only check a variable type you can use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) or === operator. e.g: == check only value, 1 == "1" is true, but === check value and type, 1 === "1" is false.

If you're new to JS I personally recommend focus in learn JavaScript and in future study other frameworks such as Typescript.

**useful study links**

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript