# Limiting values to a variable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I'm not sure if this question makes sense but when I'm using an IDE and for example I type:

```js
x = 5
s = typeof(x)
if (s === ) //Cursor selection after === (before i finished the statement)
```

the IDE's autocomplete feature gives me a list of the possible values. And if I type value that doesn't exist in that list it's highlighted, and when I execute the program (in other examples, not this one), it throws an error.

I want to achieve a similar functionality with my own variables so that I can *only* assign specific values to it.

Comment: Type inference and enum types make this possible. Use TypeScript-based autocompletion.

Comment: @Bergi, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Basically what @CertainPerformance wrote below. If you use an IDE that employs TypeScript for JS linting and autocompletion, it would work with the `typeof` example from your question out of the box. To define your *own* types and declare your variables, you'd need to use TypeScript proper though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript).

For example, your code will throw a TypeScript error if you try to compare the result of `typeof` against anything that isn't a proper JavaScript type:

```
x = 5
s = typeof(x)
if (s === 'foobar') {
}
```

results in

[image]

In a reasonable IDE with TypeScript (such as VSCode), any line of code that doesn't make sense from a type perspective will be highlighted with the error.

If you want to permit only particular values for some variable, you can use `|` to alternate, eg:

```
let someString: 'someString' | 'someOtherString' = 'someString';
```

will mean that only those two strings can occur when doing

```
someString =
```

later.

TypeScript makes writing large applications *so much easier*. It does take some time to get used to, but it's well worth it IMO. It turns many hard-to-debug runtime errors into (usually) trivially-fixable compile-time errors.