# nodejs lock a variable to only accept an int, string, bool..etc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, variables, integer

How do you lock a variable as to only accept **int** , **string** , **bool** ..**etc**? such as :

```
var test : int = 0;
var test2 : String = "test";
```

is it possible?

Comment: Not possible in JavaScript. You can look into [TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript) or other type enabling tools like [Flow](https://flow.org/) or [Tern.js](https://ternjs.net/). But they don't "lock" the value - they provide tooling to alert you if you assign `test = "hello"`. Also, no tool I know of allows you to check for *integers*. You can limit to *numbers*, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not possible to do with raw Node.js, because it is just a runtime for JavaScript. If you want to have strong types you should use TypeScript.

Here is useful reading for you on how to set up Node.js project with TypeScript https://blog.logrocket.com/typescript-with-node-js-and-express/

Comment: Oh okej, :/
it's a bit messy when creating a function given no instructions on what the params type is

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in Javascript, but you can do it in Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript do no have types. Your can implement a "custom base class" to self verify values of yours properties, before set a value.

Other option is **TypeScript**: https://www.typescriptlang.org/