# why using PayloadAction<> type instead of type any in typeScript?

Tags: redux-saga

Here is my Code which works perfect in both conditions

```js
export function* Login(action: PayloadAction<ILogin>) {
  try {
    //some code here
  } catch {}
}

export function* Login(action: any) {
  try {
    //some code here
  } catch {}
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is TypeScript and why would I use it in place of JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.