# Add properties to object conditionally with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making a simple Typescript function which creates an object with specific properties conditionally.

Here's how to use it:

```
const myObject = fancyObject({
  [addIf(true, 'a')]: "you'll see this",
  [addIf(false, 'b')]: "you'll NOT see this",
  c: "and you'll see this also"
})

console.log(myObject)
/*
 {
  a: "you'll see this",
  c: "and you'll see this also"
 }
*/
```

In context, it's working fine.
However, I am having some troubles correcting my types.

Here's the source code:

```
const REMOVE_CONST = 'removeMe'
const addIf = <T extends string>(condition: boolean, key: T): T | typeof REMOVE_CONST => {
  if (condition) return key
  else return REMOVE_CONST
}

function fancyObject<T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(POJO: T) {
  const { [REMOVE_CONST]: _REMOVE_CONST_VAL, ...POJO_ } = POJO
  return POJO_ as Omit<T, typeof REMOVE_CONST>
}
```

Let's take this example:

```
const myObj = fancyObject({
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'banana',
  c: 'cajo',
  [addIf(true, 'd')]: () => 'mew',
})
```

The problem is that the return type is always wrong. it's not the result I desire.

When you hover over `myObj`, the type is:

```
const myObj: Omit<{
    [x: string]: string | (() => "mew");
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}, "removeMe">
```

which is wrong, it should be one of the following:

```
// this is the best result ever:
type MyObjType = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d: () => string; // if addIf was (false), then you shouldn't see d at all in the type.
};
// if not possible, I'm okay with this result:
type MyObjType = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d?: () => string;
};
```

Can you help me figure this out?

- [GitHub](https://github.com/samislam/fancy-object)
- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fancy-object)

Comment: Will this end up being a runtime feature? I asked specifically because of this line: `d: () => string; // if addIf was (false), then you shouldn't see d at all in the type.`

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon, I don't understand.

Comment: You see, in the end, [Typescript has little to no effect in your program at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71616331/16770846).

Comment: alright, I was sure that's the case, then I can't have this type, ok, then how to get the second type example? the one of `// if not possible, I'm okay with this result:`

Comment: Well in the case of the second one, `d` is an optional `key` which is a [callable that returns a string](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions).

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon, alright. can you help me ?

Comment: This would work iff the type that's being passed into `addIf` had a boolean type that was either `true` or `false` - not `boolean`. Is this what you're trying to do? (e.g., if the typescript type system, not javascript, knew that a value was `true` in compile-time, then it can say that the property on that object does exist).

Comment: Also, is there a reason (not too related to the actual question at hand), that in your implementation of `addIf`, you return a string instead of a symbol when the condition doesn't exist?

Comment: The API and design you want is **impossible** because using a union in a computed property key results in a string index signature, effectively losing the type information. https://tsplay.dev/mAPpvN

Answer (score 0):

While I'm against this type of object construction, if you rework your `addIf` function to accept an object instead, you can reach something similar to what you are trying to achieve:

```js
const addIf = <P extends boolean, T extends Record<string, unknown>>(condition: P, obj: T) => {
  return (condition ? obj : Object.create(null)) as P extends true ? (P extends false ? Partial<T> : T) : {};
}
```

For an always true condition, the result is the `obj` argument's type unchanged.

```js
addIf(true, { "a": "you'll see this" });
// ^? const addIf: <true, { a: string; }>(condition: true, obj: { a: string; }) => { a: string; }
```

For an always false condition, the result is an empty object.

```js
addIf(false, { "b": "you'll NOT see this" });
// ^? const addIf: <false, { b: string; }>(condition: false, obj: { b: string; }) => {}
```

For an actual condition, the result is the `obj` argument's type, but fed through `Partial` to make each property optional.

```js
const condition = typeof window === "object";
// ^? const condition: boolean

addIf(condition, { "a": "you'll see this" });
// ^? const addIf: <boolean, { a: string; }>(condition: boolean, obj: { a: string; }) => { a?: string | undefined; }
```

Then when you need to use this helper method, you call it along with the spread operator.

```js
const myObject = {
  ...addIf(true, { "a": "you'll see this" }),
  ...addIf(false, { "b": "you'll NOT see this" }),
  c: "and you'll see this also"
}

myObject
// ^? const myObject: { "a": string, "c": string }
```

---

**Note:** If the type should display the strings as their actual value, such as `{ "a": "you'll see this" }` instead of `{ "a": string }`, you need to declare the value as a constant.

```js
const myObject = {
  ...addIf(true, { "a": "you'll see this" as const }),
  ...addIf(false, { "b": "you'll NOT see this" as const }),
  c: "and you'll see this also" as const
}

myObject
// ^? const myObject: { "a": "you'll see this", "c": "and you'll see this also" }
```