# How to use JavaScript instead of typescript in nx monorepo setup for NextJS?

Tags: next.js, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I want to create NextJS monorepo using nx using javascript. I don't want to use TypeScript for my project. But I didn't found any solution or documentation or any blog in web.
My question is:
Can I create nx monorepo of NextJS without using typescript?
If yes how can I?
or
Is there any another or alternative way to create nx monorepo of NextJS without Typescript.

---

Below command is used to create NextJS monorepo but here by default typescript is enabled

```
nx g @nrwl/next:app my-new-app
```

Docs of nx for NextJS: https://nx.dev/packages/next

---

#### Edit: 1

I know that most of the packages are written in typescript and typescript. I think nx and NextJS also uses typescript.

I want to generate NextJS application setup in javascript.
For example when we create new NextJS application we have two options

##### First (JavaScript setup `.jsx`)

```
yarn create next-app
```

##### Second (TypeScript setup `.tsx`)

```
yarn create next-app --typescript
```

Reference: [NextJS docs to create new application](https://nextjs.org/docs)

When we create NextJS application using nx command its by default create typescript setup. But when I want to create it for JavaScript.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

There actually is a `--js` flag option to generate a next.js application using JavaScript instead of TypeScript in a nx workspace. For some reason it is not stated in the official docs.

Here's an example:

```
nx g @nrwl/next:application my-app --js
```

---

In case you are using VSCode I'd also recommend using the Nx Console extension (`nrwl.angular-console`). It helps a lot when generating apps, libs, components etc and shows you all available options including the `--js` option as a neat checkbox.

Comment: I will try it and accept this answer as most helpful answer. Thank you for your answer!
Is there any disadvantage of using `--js` instead of `typescript`

Comment: Well, this is a totally different question regarding pros and cons of programming languages. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694530/what-is-typescript-and-why-would-i-use-it-in-place-of-javascript) might be helpful.